# Write txt file in linux for .net Core (Docker)

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, rhel, streamwriter

I am new in Linux and my API was created in .net core and running in Docker. The system i create will write/create a txt file that will input all errors logged in the API. My code to write is this

```
public class WriteLogs
{

    public void ErrorLogFile(string traceNo, string errorMsg)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Startup.errorPath);
        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            dir.Create();
        }

        using (StreamWriter swLog = File.AppendText(Startup.errorPath + Startup.errorFileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt"))
        {
            swLog.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " - Trace Number : " + traceNo + "   " + errorMsg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

the value in my startup is located in my appSettings.json file :

```
"ErrorPath": "C:\\BP\\", "ErrorFileName": "BP-ParamLogs_",
```

This is working in windows environment but when i transfer my program to linux and change the ErrorPath to:

```
"ErrorPath": "/home/Logs/",
```

the file was not created.

My question is, do my syntax works in linux to write txt file or my path was wrong?

Comment: Turn your slashes (`"ErrorPath": "/home/Logs/"`) and also check if you have a write access to `/home/Logs/`

Comment: what is the error message? maybe it is helpful to wrap your code in a `try-catch`-block to get the error message. I am assuming that you have to reference the path like `/home/Logs/`

Comment: Hi Daniel, theres no error being displayed, its just it didnt create the logs in the server

Comment: tried writing the path to `/home/Logs/` but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question about the syntax. `\home\Logs\` should be `/home/Logs/` as Linux uses forward-slash for path separator.

There's a chance that your program does not have write access to the `/home/` directory. I've personally tried a similar program and I ran into `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` during the logs directory creation step.

Try running your program from the terminal with `dotnet run` to see the exception you might be getting. If you are also running into the `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` then run as root with `sudo dotnet run`

Comment: Hi Sir, how can i use dotnet run if my program is an API and run in docker?

Answer (score 0):

i just solved the problem by using command:

`find . -name BP-Param*`

from the first directory. After executing it. it was in the docker directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am also just getting into Docker and Linux. My high level problem statement is to have a Python container that will generate a ML model on demand. That model needs to be stored on a shared volume to be picked up by another container that will be used to service requests for predictions from that model.

Anyway, in getting my feet wet I was simply trying to write a file to a shared volume. I was running into System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to access any data on the shared volume. I did not think the answer from hforeste above applied but I could be wrong and would love to be corrected if that is the case.

Here is my environment.

- Host - Windows 11 professional
- Docker Desktop (DD)
- Using linux containers (WSL2 not Hyper-V config for DD)
- .NET Core 8 Console Application

Here is what I did to get it to work (means write to the shared volume and read back from the shared volume with NET core console application.) Credit given to Docker Deep Dive by Nigel Poulton as I am using his book to lead me through my learnings and find it very concise and helpful. Here are the steps.

1. docker run -it --name voltainer --mount source=bizvol,target=/vol alpine
2. Shell should be open for the alpine container now.
3. chmod -R 777 /vol (this is for learning of course so I understand the implications of doing this)
4. docker run -it --name MyNetCoreContainerName --mount source=bizvol,target=/vol MyNetCoreImageName

At this point my Net Core application is able to access, read and write to the /vol directory on the shared volume with code like below.

```
try
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid();
    File.WriteAllText($"/vol/{fileName}",Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("No exception happened");
    var result = File.ReadAllText($"/vol/{fileName}");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}

while (true)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

I hope this can help someone out.